# How to update Jenkins secret text via REST API

Tags: jenkins

I need to update the jenkins secret text. Initially I am creating credentials from UI but later in jenkins build I want to update the value to different value. Is there any way I can perform update via REST API.

I find few thread but doesn't solve my problem as I need to update the secret.

UPDATE: I am able to create secret using REST API

```
curl -X POST 'https://user:token@Jenkins_Server:port_number/jenkins/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' \
--data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
   "credentials": { 
   "scope": "GLOBAL", 
   "id": "myID", 
   "secret": "mysecret", 
   "description": "myDecription", 
   "$class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl" 
  } 
}'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able find that using below

```
$ cat credential.xml
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>myId</id>
  <secret>mysecret</secret>
  <description>Test</description>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl>
$ curl -X POST -H content-type:application/xml -d @credential.xml 'https://user:password@jenkins_server:8080/jenkins/credentials/store/system/domain/_/credential/myId/config.xml'
```

After posting this curl multiple times I was able to update the secrets from jenkins build.